# Is there a maven docker image using AWS linux 2023 as the base?

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

Per https://hub.docker.com/_/maven I see plenty of images (ie https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/51eeb2469d11acbafd4a3be13f8339ff556292fc/amazoncorretto-17/Dockerfile) that uses AWS Linux 2023 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/install-docker.html)? I see plenty of that have amazonlinux:2 as the base image (ie https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux/) . Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: probably it is not there, you can file issue like [this](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/pull/289/files) to get it included in their repo or you can take reference of the changes and build one for yourself like [this](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/pull/289/files)